# Port number appending to email from EXM

Tags: exm

When I am sending an email through EXM 3.4 and add our email to the message (as a way for customers to respond to us) it will always append the port number to the mailto link.

For example, marketing@test.com:25

How can we make it that the :25 is not added on to the email mailto link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a known issue which has been fixed in  3.5 release. Check the release notes of 3.5 .

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email%20Experience%20Manager/35/Email%20Experience%20Manager%2035%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

[image]

If you cannot upgrade your exm version i would suggest to raise a support ticket and get a patch for this.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @prabhat this is indeed a known issue, and it's fixed in the 3.5 release.

The issue only happens if you're sending a quick-test email. This should not be an issue when you're sending emails to actual recipients.

If upgrading to 3.5 is not a solution, you can fix the problem by overriding the Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.GenerateLink.Hyperlink.EncryptQueryString pipeline processor.

You need to add replace the check that looks something like this:

```
if((uri.Scheme.Equals("http") && uri.Port == 80) || (uri.Scheme.Equals("https") && uri.Port == 443))
{
  uri.Port = -1;
}
```

with something that also checks for mailto and port 25, e.g.

```
if((uri.Scheme.Equals("http") && uri.Port == 80) || (uri.Scheme.Equals("https") && uri.Port == 443) || (uri.Scheme.Equals("mailto") && uri.Port == 25))
{
  uri.Port = -1;
}
```